# Using a ternary operator without assigning it to a variable

Tags: c

I know this is possible, but is it good practice to use a ternary operator to call functions rather than using an if statement?

```
if(x){
   a();
} else if(y){
   b();
} else if(z){
   c();
}
```

Instead do this:

```
(x) ? 
   a() : 
(y) ? 
   b() : 
(z) ? 
   c() : 0;
```

Is there an unknown issues that can occur that I do not know of?

Comment: The first is so much more readable.

Comment: What about with formatting now? @chris

Comment: is it in c or c++ or both?

Comment: The fact is people aren't used to seeing the conditional operator used like an if-else chain. It wouldn't take too long to figure out, but you have to stop reading to think about it, which you don't have to do with the first.

Comment: @DilipKumar C, sorry.

Comment: You may run into trouble if `a`, `b` and `c` have different return types.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the second is likely the more useful version in a macro, should you need to do this. In that case you can fix any differing return type problems with the comma operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the nitty-gritty details of how the conditinal operator works, see the [C11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 6.5.15.

The biggest difference is that the conditional (ternary) operator is meant to be used specifically for assigning to a value.  As in,

`x = (a < b) ? c : d`

If `(a < b)` is not zero (true), `x = c`; otherwise, `x = d`.

There are several constraints on `c` and `d` that need to be considered (see 6.5.15.3).  Chief among them is that `c` and `d` must be one of the following:

- Both arithmetic types
- Both the same `struct` or `union` type
- Both void types
- Both pointers (or can be converted to such)

Now all of that said, you're specifically not assigning to a variable, but the return values of those functions need to hold to these constraints as well.

However, as was pointed out in the comments on the question - this is still sacrificing readability for terseness.  That's almost never best practice.

**Many thanks to @JensGustedt for pointing out the errors in my answer and helping me to fix them!!

Comment: Unfortunately your answer is not correct about the types. There is nothing in the standard about compatible types, this is just the wrong concept here. The important cases are that `c` and `d` are of arithmetic type, are the *same* `struct` or `union` type, or are pointers (or can be converted to). And your para about functions that don't return a value is completely incomprehensible.

Comment: @JensGustedt - Doesn't section 6.5.15.2 enforce the notion that the types of `c` and `d` in my example above have to have the same/compatible types? That's how I interpreted that paragraph of the standard - I'm not sure how my answer is wrong then.  As for the paragraph you noted - I'm not talking about functions that *don't* return a value, but rather arguing that the function *must* return an *int*, as that's what `0` is in the OP's example.  I can change the wording if that's not clear (or if it's dead wrong).  I'm just trying to get a better sense of why I'm incorrect - thank you!

Comment: "compatible type" is a technical term with very specific meaning in the standard. Here, for arithmetic types for example, the standard arithmetic conversions are done, so it is completely fine to have `int` and `double` or other similar combinations. The `0` doesn't force return an `int`. It could be any arithmetic type or even a pointer, that would  all work with the special value `0` as well.

Comment: Ah - didn't realize that "compatible type" is a technical term.  And I see now that 6.5.15.5 talks about the conversions.  Thank you! Should I delete this answer outright, or is there a way to mark it as incorrect and preserve these comments for posterity?

Comment: Your answer is not completely wrong, so one option could be to edit and correct it. (But if you don't hurry, the question will probably be closed, anyhow)